# I could not connect Tomcat deployed in ec2 instance from my local sand box

Tags: aws-ec2-instance-connect

Here is the output on my ec2 instance

```
[root@ip-172-31-15-53 bin]# sudo netstat -atpn  | grep 8080
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1752/java
```

when I  telnet

```
172-31-15-53 8080. connect to 172-31-15-53 failed.
```

also it failed while accessing tomcat homepage.

Anyone please help me to fix this issue..